# Getting an Error - Trying to show wall on my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting the error below for the graph API call:

`https://graph.facebook.com/[MYID]/feed?limit=100&access_token=[TOKEN]`

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "SETTINGS: Unrecognized pref_type 0 for NullProfileSettings pref name default_non_connection_tab.",
    "type": "Exception"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check and recheck your app id. 
I had a same problem for few days untill I realized that the app id was wrong.

Go to Graph API Explorer in facebook developer page.
Type in your app id and check if in the result is
a) Your page name
b) Id is the same as you typed in. If not then you should use that one instead.

Hope that helps